# Run a script wrapper instead of the real application in KDE

Tags: linux, debian, kde, application-launch

I am trying to limit the time my kids are playing Minecraft on our home PC (Debian 11 Bullseye). This is a family PC, used occassionally by everyone, so we are always logged in using a single user account.

To mitigate the issue, I wrote a small bash script that checks the current time, and if is outside of bounds then it shows a message box instead of starting the game. But now I stuggle how to swap the command configured for the icons in KDE. When I changed Exec in `/usr/share/applications/minecraft-launcher.desktop` it doesn't seem to have any effect, the game is executed without the script. How can I edit the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Is your desktop entry being overridden by the system? If so, you can try creating a user entry in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Also try right-clicking the minecraft icon, edit-application, and make sure it is the correct desktop entry.

Finally, make sure your script works by running the script directly.